# How to get contact from iphone simulator

Tags: iphone

I want to get all contact details from the iphone simulator, I have already read different questions related to this question ,still i am not able to do the job. I am new to iPhone programming, 
so help me from the scratch. Give me any link for tutorial that defines all things step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code for the accessing address book

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    contactList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ABAddressBookRef m_addressbook = ABAddressBookCreate();

    if (!m_addressbook) {
        NSLog(@"opening address book");
    }

    CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(m_addressbook);
    CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(m_addressbook);

    for (int i=0;i &lt; nPeople;i++) { 
        NSMutableDictionary *dOfPerson=[NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

        ABRecordRef ref = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople,i);

        //For username and surname
        ABMultiValueRef phones =(NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
        CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
        firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        [dOfPerson setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName] forKey:@"name"];

        //For Email ids
        ABMutableMultiValueRef eMail  = ABRecordCopyValue(ref, kABPersonEmailProperty);
        if(ABMultiValueGetCount(eMail) &gt; 0) {
            [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(eMail, 0) forKey:@"email"];

        }

        //For Phone number
        NSString* mobileLabel;
        for(CFIndex i = 0; i &lt; ABMultiValueGetCount(phones); i++) {
            mobileLabel = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(phones, i);
            if([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString *)kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
            }
            else if ([mobileLabel isEqualToString:(NSString*)kABPersonPhoneIPhoneLabel])
            {
                [dOfPerson setObject:(NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phones, i) forKey:@"Phone"];
                break ;
            }

        [contactList addObject:dOfPerson];
        CFRelease(ref);
        CFRelease(firstName);
        CFRelease(lastName);
    }
    NSLog(@"array is %@",contactList);
    }
}
```

May this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource` of  [**ABPersonRef**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople).

```
CFArrayRef ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSource (
   ABAddressBookRef addressBook,
   ABRecordRef source
);
```